# Keep root element after updating XML from dataset

Tags: xml

I have written a program to update an XML file with specific values. I have run the program and confirmed that it works successfully except for the root element. The XML file is loaded into a dataset from which the user can update the values. After this is done, the new data is written to a new XML file.

The original XML file would look something like this:

```
<dl:XMLDataDelivery xsi:schemaLocation=http://www.somesite.org/filename.xsd xmlns:dl=http://www.somesite.org/filename xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<PartInformation>
     <PartName>Hex Bolt</PartName>
     <DetailedInfo>
       <PartNumber>88-901</PartNumber>
       <SerialNumber>SN1234</SerialNumber>
     </DetailedInfo>
  </PartInformation>
</dl:XMLDataDelivery>
```

However after the update the XML changes to something like this:

```
<dl:XMLDataDelivery xmlns:dl=http://www.somesite.org/filename>
<PartInformation>
     <PartName>Hex Bolt</PartName>
     <DetailedInfo>
       <PartNumber>88-901</PartNumber>
       <SerialNumber>SN1234</SerialNumber>
     </DetailedInfo>
  </PartInformation>
</dl:XMLDataDelivery>
```

I've tried several methods to add the missing data back to the root element with no luck. I looked at changing the namespace of the dataset but that only allows for editing versus adding. I also tried to create new attributes to add, but have been unsuccessful there too. Here's just one of the many things that I've tried (NOTE this comes after the dataset.WriteXML(fileName):

```
    'Dim xDoc As New XmlDocument
    'Dim ns As XmlNamespaceManager

    'xDoc.Load(newFileString)
    'Dim xAtt As XmlAttribute = xDoc.CreateAttribute("xsi:schemaLocation")
    'xAtt.Value = "http://www.somesite.org/filename"
    'xDoc.Attributes.Append(xAtt)

    'ns = New XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable)
    'ns.AddNamespace("xsi:SchemaLocation", "http://www.somesite.org/filename")
    'xDoc.Save("thisXML.xml")
```

Any help to get the root element back to the original form or edit the current one would be great. Thanks very much to all. (Let me know if more code would be needed to properly assess this)

Comment: So I believe I have just figured out this problem using the answer from the question asked [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a97c29e4-d1cc-4d21-a66c-7181813adc14/adding-xsischemalocation-using-the-object-xmldocument?forum=xmlandnetfx)

The only thing I'm wondering is if the attribute order matters since the xlmns:dl & xsi:schemaLocation are switched around...

Comment: [Note that the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or empty-element tag is not significant.](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost forgot to provide the answer from my comment (sorry)...

I added the following code after the dataset update and writeXML functions:

```
    Dim xDoc As New XmlDocument
    Dim schemaLocation As XmlAttribute = Nothing
    Dim schemaString As String = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    Dim schemaValue As String = "http://www.somesite.org/filename.xsd"

    xDoc.Load(newFileString)
    schemaLocation = xDoc.CreateAttribute("xsi", "schemaLocation", schemaString)
    schemaLocation.Value = schemaValue
    xDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttributeNode(schemaLocation)
    xDoc.Save(newFileString)
```

So now the root attributes appear as:

```
<dl:XMLDataDelivery xmlns:dl="http://www.somesite.org/filename" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.somesite.org/filename.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

from which kennyzx confirmed that the order was not important. As I mentioned in the comments I adapted the answer provided in this [MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a97c29e4-d1cc-4d21-a66c-7181813adc14/adding-xsischemalocation-using-the-object-xmldocument?forum=xmlandnetfx) to solve my problem.